# How to split a string without losing any char in java

Tags: java, string, split

I'm using eclipse for java.

I want to split an input line from user without losing any char.

For example input line is: `+2+ sqrt(25   )-41*3- abs(-4)-62 /2`

And the output should be : `+2,+sqrt(25),-41,*3,-abs(-4),-62,/2`

(If I split with "+" or etc. the char "+" itself will be remove.)

What should I do ?

My code is something like this :

```
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    String str= scanner.nextLine();
    String[] parts;
    parts = str.split("!?!?!!?!");  // i don't know what to put here
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: please refrain from asking logic related questions as this may have multiple solutions and is far off topic. always upload the code that you have tried and the error you are getting

Comment: Remove the spaces and replace the operators with itself plus a prefixed comma.

Comment: @vikeng21 the code is now added

Comment: Now you need to write a parser. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Regular Expression in Java assuming that **you can't have Nested Parenthesis** (this is a strict necessity)

```
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();

    String input = "+2+ sqrt(25 )-41*3- abs(-4)-62 /2";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\+\\-/\\*][^\\+\\-\\*/\\(]+(\\([^\\(\\)]*\\))?");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        parts.add(m.group());
    }
```

If you want an array you cant do :

```
    parts.toArray(new String[parts.size()]);
```

This will give you a simple array of String. I am using Java Collections to handle the array creation because there is no way to know the size of the array before parsing the String

Explanations about this regex : 
`[\\+\\-/\\*]` looks for an operator sign
`[^\\+\\-\\*/\\(]+` looks for everything except operators and left parenthesis
`(\\([^\\(\\)]*\\))?`looks for a parenthesis content without nested parenthesis

This code gives :

```
+2
+ sqrt(25 )
-41
*3
- abs(-4)
-62 
/2
```

If you need nested parenthesis, then you need to implement a Parser, and I let you google it.

Comment: It works ! how I can put the result in a string array ?

Comment: in my program I need it in string array (for example it's name is `parts[]`) because I need only to put it in `for(x:y)`    for example: `for (String string : parts)`

Comment: See my edit for Strings array